# jQuery ON function with values assigned to parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to delegate a function with a change in radio button selection.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('change', 'radioBtnName', function(e){
        $(this).after('<p>"No click me!"</p>');   
    });
});​
```

What I want to be able to do is to pass some values to the handler function. Like

```
{param1:"hell", param2:"world"}
```

And then to access these values inside the function (e) by

```
e.data.param1
```

How do I include these parameters and give them values in setting the delegate. I am creating the radio buttons on the fly and want to associate the function with a change in selection.

Comment: What do the values associate with? Are they per button?

Comment: Use `data-` attributes.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/zemapeteha/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @GoneCoding no, in actual program this is inside another function which calculates and build a complex object with some nested arrays of objects etc. So there are three categories represented by the radio button and on change event i want to be able to send this complex object to another function to to do some processing based on the selection done on radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right you want to pass extra parameters with the `.on()` method. I hope the following example helps you.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#radioBlock input[type="radio"]', {param1: 'hell', param2: 'world'},  function(e){
    console.log(e.data.param1);   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="radioBlock">
  <input type="radio" id="one" name="one" value="One">
  <input type="radio" id="two" name="two" value="Two">
  <input type="radio" id="three" name="three" value="Three">
</div>
```

Comment: What is the point of delegated event handlers *that target only one specific ID selection*? This is not a very maintainable solution. Better off `data-` driving it.

Comment: @GoneCoding I'm absolutely with you and would myself do it the way you proposed. I merely wanted to show that the `.on()` method offers a way to pass extra parameters (and that's the way I read the question, might be wrong of course). In the end it's the OP's decision which solution he gets along best with.

Comment: @Flyer53 I like the fact that I can pass the parameter values to the handler function and for me it appears more suitable however I would like to ask here then how we select one group of radio buttons (no just one of them with the id)? can the name property be used here to cover the change in group?

Comment: I have found the solution with a combination of your and @SaumyaRastogi solutions. Dont know how to divide the credit.

Comment: @Novice I changed the example to work with a classname as selector. So you need only one handler ... but only if all radio buttons of this class use the same extra parameters

Comment: we dont need to use extra class. I think what @Sauma has given for selection is better because it is selecting a group of radio buttons with their enclosing element in my case a fieldset.

Comment: @Novice Fully correct! I changed my example again to reflect this ... used a div, but of course works with a fieldset as well...

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up with in my solution.

Comment: Well then ... keep on coding ;)

Answer (score 4):

This could be easily done with `data-*` attributes if they are per element. So have the button with:

```
<input type="radio" data-param1="hell" data-param2="world" />
```

And get them using:

```
$(this).data("param1");
$(this).data("param2");
```

Also, if you call the [`$(this).data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/), it will return you the whole `data` object.

Comment: can we put a complex object in data-param1 instead of a simple string? I have a complex object to be passed to the function which handles the change in radio button selection.

Comment: @Novice You can put a JSON through `data` but in the processing, use `JSON.parse()` and get the objects.

Comment: You will have problems with the double-quotes terminating your HTML attributes if you embed JSON data as-is.

Comment: @Novice See the second parameter here: http://jsbin.com/paqiceniqa/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I am leaving office and I'll be offline for some time... `:(`

Comment: @PraveenKumar The demo only shows one radio button. I am creating a group of radio buttons on the fly. How do I add this handler to all of them and pass the same parameter object to the handler function. How about a fieldset enclosing all the radio buttons in a group?

Answer (score 1):

Store them as data attributes on the radio buttons:

```
$(document).on('change', 'radioBtnName', function(e){
    var $button = $(this);
    var param1 = $button.data("param1");
    var param2 = $button.data("param2");
    // do whatever you want with the values :)   
});
```

Note use `document` instead of `body` for delegated events. This avoids the need for a DOM ready handler (and avoids a bug with `body`)

Comment: Hey, you are back? How are you?

Comment: Just wasting my time as usual. I see the way SO works has not changed at all :)

Comment: LoL. Man. You haven't changed at all. Anyways. Nice to meet you again.

Comment: @Andy: Cut & paste error from original :) Took that out completely as not revelant

Comment: Sorry, I meant you've already assigned `$(this)` to `$button`. No need to use `$(this)` again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this).data()` like this:

```js
$(function() {
  
  $("body").on('click', "#radioBlock input[type='radio']", function(e) {
 
 alert('Data Value - ' + $(this).data('value'));

  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radioBlock">

  <label> <input type='radio' name='radio_input' data-value='1'> Radio 1 </label>
  <label> <input type='radio' name='radio_input' data-value='2'> Radio 2 </label>
  <label> <input type='radio' name='radio_input' data-value='3'> Radio 3 </label>

</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it does. I have made my solution by combining yours and @Flyer53 solution.

Comment: @Novice - Hahaha it's great to hear that you find your solution, by the way you can atleast give us both upvotes... Else it depends on you to choose the accepted answer